# IntelliJ IDEA 12 tomcat working directory

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm quite new to java dev and I'm having an issue setting the working directory of my local tomcat server in IntelliJ to the root directory of my project. I've had to go into my tomcat libexec folder and symlink a folder so that a relative path file can be found. How would I go about telling tomcat where to look for these files